# BreadthFirstScan for implicit Graph

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

Many algorithms on graphs require only local knowledge at each step, *e.g.* for BFS at any point we only need to know the `AdjacencyList` of the vertex we are currently looking at. BFS is implemented in Mathematica in `BreadthFirstScan`, but I see no way to use it on an implicit graph, *i.e.* not a `Graph` object, but an object for which we can compute edges on-demand for any particular node.

More generally, is there any way to work with implicitly defined graphs in Mathematica? I've tried to trick it into accepting a "graph association", specifying the number of vertices and the function to use to compute neighbors of a vertex:

```
Unprotect@GraphQ;
GraphQ[Graph[a_Association]] := With[{}, Print@"call: GraphQ"; With[{}, Print@"call: GraphQ"; KeyExistsQ[a, "n"] && KeyExistsQ[a, "adj"]];
Protect@GraphQ;

Unprotect@VertexList;
VertexList[Graph[a_Association]] := With[{}, Print@"call: VertexList"; Range@a@"n"];
Protect@VertexList;

Unprotect@EdgeList;
EdgeList[Graph[a_Association]] := With[{}, Print@"call: EdgeList"; Flatten@Table[v \[DirectedEdge] # & /@ a["adj"]@v, {v, a@"n"}]];
Protect@EdgeList;

Unprotect@VertexCount;
VertexCount[Graph[a_Association]] := With[{}, Print@"call: VertexCount"; a@"n"];
Protect@VertexCount;

Unprotect@AdjacencyList;
AdjacencyList[Graph[a_Association], v_] := With[{}, Print@"call: AdjacencyList"; a["adj"]@v];
Protect@AdjacencyList;
```

Then, for example, the following would be an equivalent definition for `CycleGraph@3`:

```
cycle3 = Graph[<|"n" -> 3, "adj" -> ({Mod[# + 1, 3, 1], Mod[# - 1, 3, 1]} &)|>];
```

However, I haven't got this graph to work for any built-in function: the furthest I've got is seeing `NeighborhoodGraph` perform some calls to `GraphQ`, `VertexList` and `EdgeList` (why would it do this?), but most functions just somehow detect this is not a native `Graph` object... any ideas how to circumvent this?

**PS:** My use case involves a huge (~10^12 vertex) graph which I know has small connected components, which I'd like to explore.

Comment: No, you can't trick it to accept something that's not really a `Graph`. I see how this would be useful, but I am pretty sure this is not possible.

Comment: Would a custom BFS implementation help you?

Comment: Indeed one certainly could write custom implementations of (at least some of) the standard algorithms, but I was looking for a quicker way to interface with them directly, for performance and correctness reasons as well as prototyping speed... it looks like Mathematica could use an `ImplicitGraph` function :-/

Comment: I think implementing something like that is a lot more effort than you might think. I would not hold my breath. You can take a look at the Boost Graph Library (C++) which is designed to work on arbitrary graph representations.

Answer (score 6):

I expect that what you are asking for is not possible. The graph functions very likely use internal functions instead of the public API. In fact, I expect many algorithms to be implemented in a low-level language like C or C++. Overriding the public API won't help.

As a workaround, you could implement BFS yourself.

```
bfs[neifun_, v0_] :=
 Module[{dist = <||>, q = CreateDataStructure["Queue"], v, d, neis},
  q["Push", v0];
  AssociateTo[dist, v0 -> 0];
  While[! q["EmptyQ"],
   v = q["Pop"];
   d = dist[v] + 1;
   neis = Select[neifun[v], Not@KeyMemberQ[dist, #] &];
   q["Push", #] & /@ neis;
   AssociateTo[dist, Thread[neis -> d]]
   ];
  dist
  ]
```

Here `v0` is the starting vertex and `neifun` is a function that returns the neighbours of a vertex. The output is an association from reached vertices to their distance from `v0`.

Example:

```
SeedRandom[555];
g = RandomGraph[{10, 10}, GraphStyle -> "DiagramGold"]
```

[image]

```
bfs[AdjacencyList[g, #] &, 1]
(* <|1 -> 0, 9 -> 1, 10 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 2, 8 -> 2, 6 -> 3, 7 -> 3|> *)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Breadth first search**

Well, BFS can be implemented using a queue which in turn is easy to implement with `Association`. First, let's emulate a query function `neigbors`:

```
G = RandomGraph[{100, 200}];
adj = AdjacencyMatrix[G]["AdjacencyLists"];
neigbors[vertex_] := adj[[vertex]];
```

Not let's implement the queue:

```
iter = 0;
counter = 0;
visited = <||>;
queue = <||>;
push[vertex_] := AssociateTo[queue, ++counter -> vertex];
pop[] := If[Length[queue] > 0,
   Module[{key, return},
    key = Keys[queue][[1]];
    return = queue[key];
    KeyDropFrom[queue, key];
    return
    ],
   $Failed
   ];
```

Let's do the breadth first search starting at vertex `1`:

```
vertex = 1;
While[vertex =!= $Failed,
  iter++;
  AssociateTo[visited, vertex -> iter];
  c = neigbors[vertex];
  unvisited = ReverseSort[Pick[c, Lookup[visited, c, -1], -1]];
  Scan[push, unvisited];
  
  vertex = pop[];
  ];
```

For example, this provides you with the vertices of the connected component of the start vertex in depth-first order:

```
 ordering = Keys[Sort[visited]]
```

**Depth first search**

Analogously, one can implement DFS by using a stack. The difference between a stack and a queue is just the end from which elements are popped. So just changing `pop` to the following should do:

```
pop[] := If[Length[queue] > 0,
   Module[{key, return},
    key = Keys[queue][[-1]];
    return = queue[key];
    KeyDropFrom[queue, key];
    return
    ],
   $Failed
   ];
```

Comment: I was a bit lazier and used the new built-in queue :-)

Comment: Yeah, is saw that right after I submitted! XD